# Can I learn UX design as I already have an idea about UI design, but not in coding?

Tags: interaction-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to know to get started as a professional UX/interaction designer?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-get-started-as-a-professional-ux-interaction-designer)

Basically am working as graphic designer and animator in the e-learning industry past 8 years.
My question is can I learn UX design as I already have an idea about UI design, but not in coding?

Comment: Questions such as this have been asked several times in the past. See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/479/how-to-become-a-user-experience-designer or http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-get-started-as-a-professional-ux-interaction-designer

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can learn about UX without coding but eventually, for most of your work, someone is going to have to code it up.  I think that having an understanding of what goes into that aspect of the interface helps you make practical decisions as a UX designer and can inspire you to try new UX ideas that you might not have come up with had you not known about some of the implementation technology.

Also, understanding the coding aspect of UX helps you communicate with other (more technical) members of your team, which makes your ideas more likely to be listened to and used.

Start by learning some HTML and CSS.  Try some JavaScript.  If you're enjoying yourself, dive into something like Python.  A little extra expertise never hurt anyone.